# sqlite not suitable for PCL development?

Tags: sqlite, portable-class-library

I'm trying to use a PCL to reuse SQLite query code across platforms. I am constantly fighting to get it to work. I had it for a bit, so I developed the Windows 8 app, but when I got to Windows Phone, I was getting errors that it was looking for a different version of SQLite.NET. Anyway, I'm thankful that I use git, because I've totally messed up my project. So far, SQLite doesn't seem like the way to go for PCL. Am I right? If so, what should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SQLitePCL.raw](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw).  It's not something you probably want to use directly, but the readme contains lots of information about using SQLite across platforms, and links to various other libraries.

SQLitePCL.raw is under active development, hopefully soon it will be considered stable and there will be libraries such as sqlite-net that build on top of it so that it's easy to use SQLite from PCLs.

Comment: It looks promising for future development. I'm thinking now that what I'll have to do is use a copy of my Data Access Object in each project and pass that into my library as an interface and call the methods from there. *yuck*

Comment: @MichaelDiLeo What prevents you from putting the DAO in a PCL?

Comment: It's weird. I had it there, but there are issues when it comes to the windows phone and windows 8 projects referencing the DAO in the PCL. It was actually a pain to get it working with the Windows 8 project (I think I had to change a target version number or something in the .csproj file among other things). When I moved on to creating the Windows Phone project, the target assemblies in the library and phone didn't seem to like each other. I finally said, "forget it," and added the DAO as a linked file into my projects and passed it to the ViewModel as an interface. That seems to have worked